# How to navigate users to open phone settings in .net maui

Tags: .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

The application will prompt the user with a control in the alert such as button, which on clicking, will open Settings of the phone.

I want this in order to navigate user to Settings>Locations>Turning on Location service in case it's off.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open the app privacy settings from xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50137886/how-to-open-the-app-privacy-settings-from-xamarin-forms)

Comment: The classes used in the two solutions of this link couldn't be found in Maui, such as Intent class, and Maui is saying Device doesn't contain a definition for OpenUri. I may have missed something. Plz point me out if any.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I tried the solution in the shared code in my project. I corrected that and moved the code to platform specific. Now the only issue is the application is able to open a settings page, but I can see just a blink of it. It immediately returning from the function to my application state. How can I retain the Settings page? I have tried the first solution in the link provided for Android platform. Pardon me, but I am most naive to native code.

Comment: *"It immediately returning from the function to my application state."* Add your current code to question.